# Losing horizontal alignment

Tags: jasper-reports, text-alignment, pdfa

I am using the following method below to convert a pdf generated from a jasper to PDFA. In the report it is set to horizontal alignment “justified” and JasperPrint is populating correctly. I noticed that it loses alignment when executing the following snippet:

Converter PdfStandardsConverter = new PdfStandardsConverter(InputFolderPath);
converter.toPdfA3A(outputfolderpath);

Is there any way to fix keep this alignment?

I tried directly manipulating Jasper information and using JasperFill but it didn't work.

Comment: Searching the e-iceblue portal I found a person with a slightly similar problem. I hadn't noticed before because I'm converting pdf to pdfA, and it was from docx to pdf.

Basically the current version of spire.pdf has the fix, but only the paid version